Django: Maintaining a local set of migrations differing from upstream
I have written patches for a Django project that take forever to be integrated upstream (or may not even be). Due to this, I have local migrations that I need to maintain.
However, due to the way the migration numbering system works, I have to update their numbers everytime upstream adds a new migrations, and that doesn't even work properly as it creates conflicts with the database state.
I've been trying to move them to a separate app, but it doesn't seem to be possible to apply them to the original app then.
How to properly maintain your own set of migrations?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/migrations/#version-control

@iklinac Yea, this does work. I think the issue is then that I misinterpreted an unrelated issue.

Two ways:

use the --merge command when django detects a collision, you will only have to resolve conflicts once, this will allow for duplicate numbers.
always delete and re-run your migrations when pulling upstream changes.

Each situation is different and it's up to your judgement to decide when you should go with 1 or 2 or switch.
Personally I almost always stick with 2 & just don't pull upstream changes unless relevant or just before merge.
However for larger projects, #1 might make more sense as it avoids having to deal with conflicts on apps that have a consistent influx of migrations.
